# Xcode UI Testing Retry on Failuire

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way to set a UI test to retry on failure? I know I should address failures, but there are occasions when I want a specific test to automatically retry immediately after the first failure. I tried adding a function in the teardown, pseudo "if test failed, then..." but nothing successfully does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use invokeTest method to retry the failed test.

From the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496282-invoketest?language=objc)

> Invoking a test performs its setup, invocation, and teardown. In general this should not be called directly.

For eg I have setup my test to retry 2 more times after initial failure. Here self.failureRetryCount is a property in the test class.

```
- (void) tearDown {
  [super tearDown];
  if (self.failureRetryCount < 2) {
     self.failureRetryCount += 1;
    [self invokeTest];
  }
}
```